# Enter key firing Gridview Row Command Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox and a gridview right below that on an aspx page. When ever I get to the page and press enter, it fires gridview onrowcommand event. Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I did google everyone suggested me to add a piece of javascript code to handle enter key event (13) . I want to know why would a page do that. Is it a web form thing or something else?

Comment: Post what code you are working with please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're witnessing is the default behavior much like hitting enter on an HTML input tag nested within form tag.

If you don't want the behavior, then you can handle it either in JavaScript as your research suggested it or in your C# code as follows:

```
protected void gvChild_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
        // do whatever you want with the event
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I appreciate it. I did get to read some more about it and it is something that's called " implicit submission" property of a form. Just like what you were talking about Casey.